# THREEjs rotating starfield

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I have a threejs scene, created in typescript in an Angular app. I have a light, camera, and a torus knot.  The torus knot rotates.

I added a starfield with this function

```
  private scene: THREE.Scene;
  private stars: THREE.Group;

  addStar = () => {
    const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 24, 24);
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      color: 0xffffff,
      emissive: 0xffffff,
      emissiveIntensity: 1,
      roughness: 0,
      metalness: 0.5
    });
    const star = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    const [x, y, z] = Array(3)
      .fill(undefined)
      .map(() => THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(100));

    star.position.set(x, y, z);
    this.stars = new THREE.Group();
    this.stars.add(star);
    this.scene.add(this.stars);
  };
```

Then, in my createScene function I call  it

```
    Array(200).fill(undefined).forEach(this.addStar);
```

and 200 stars are indeed added to my scene, at random locations as expected.

However, in my animate function I am trying to rotate the start group around its center

```
    this.stars.rotation.y += 0.005;
```

but I only see 1 star moving.  What did I miss?

Comment: Looks like you are creating a new group for each star? So there's only one star for each group? The creation of your star group should be outside the add star function.

Comment: that was it, thanks